# How to register thread using pj_thread_register() in PJSIP swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, pjsip

I write a code in swift file but generate compiler error.
[image]

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you add the necessary imports?

Comment: yes actually i'm getting this error 
Calling pjlib from unknown/external thread. You must " "register external threads with pj_thread_register() " "before calling any pjlib functions. in IOS